# Removing or replacing a post supporting a bolted joint in a long glue lam beam

Tags: steel, post, beam, engineering

We bought a home to remodel - and taking down a wall we found that our gluelam beam is actually two different beams, held together with some steel and bolts, and supported by a 4x6 vertical timber. We don't think this was a part of the original design - but don't hate it enough to pay for engineering to replace the beam with one single piece...

So... any ideas on what we could do? Steel post of much smaller dimension?

Any creative ideas are appreciated!

[image: beam in middle of kitchen island location]

Comment: Is there some reason they might have had for cutting that beam?  Or did they just not want to pay for a longer gluelam?

Comment: Ideas about what you can do about what specifically.

Comment: I'm not certain what your question is, so if my edit is wrong, please use the "edited" link above to undo the edit.

Comment: It looks to me as a tie point for 3 lambs, taking the post out could be a really bad idea without properly verifying the load requirements. Thick wall round would make a nice steel support.

Comment: To have any hope of accurate communication - horizontal load supporting element = **beam.** Vertical load supporting element = **post.** You are apparently asking about replacing a wooden post with a steel post. while calling them beams? You won't (I suspect - your engineer will confirm or refute) be able to make it "much smaller" due to a delightful failure mode of "slender columns" known as buckling.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the language better - very helpful - basics are good - I think we have decided to maintain the post - but perhaps beef up the strapping it has to the beam. (unless there are other creative ideas out there yet...)

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. The original goal was never specified, the OP abandoned plans, and it seems to border on a design/decorating question to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot going on at that point in your roof. I would strongly recommend you get a civil engineer to have a look if you are considering removing the post.

If you only want to replace the post with a steel column, that would be simple. You can google the strength of a wood column in the dimensions you have and select a similar or stronger steel pole.

From the picture I can confirm that it is a load bearing pillar, the beam that stretches from the windows toward the 4 x 6 vertical timber is transferring it's load to the timber.

Comment: Not only do you NEED a structural engineer to advise you on what you can do, you need one to tell you if what you DO have is proper and adequate. That connection where the top of the post meets the beams looks scary inadequate.